# GDI+ zoom in/out base on mouse pointer

Tags: c#, gdi+

I want to zoom in/out vector graphics base on mouse pointer as center.
My code like that:

```
Matrix m_globalMatrix = new Matrix();
PointF m_scalePos;
float m_perZoom = 1.2f;
float m_zoom = 1f;
void ReCoord(){
    m_globalMatrix.Reset();
    m_globalMatrix.Translate(m_scalePos.X, m_scalePos.Y);
    m_globalMatrix.Scale(m_zoom, m_zoom); 
    m_globalMatrix.Translate(-m_scalePos.X, -m_scalePos.Y);
}
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        //PointF temp;

        //temp = CoordTransform(e.Location);
        m_scalePos = (PointF)ScreenToCoord(e.Location);
        Console.WriteLine("m_scalePos:{0},Zoom:{1}", m_scalePos, m_zoom);

        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            m_zoom /= m_perZoom;
        }
        else
        {
            m_zoom *= m_perZoom;
        }

        ReCoord();

        Invalidate();
    }
 public CoordPoint ScreenToCoord(PointF screenPoint)
    {
        PointF[] points = new PointF[] { screenPoint };
        Matrix mx = m_globalMatrix.Clone();
        mx.TransformPoints(points);

        /*
        mx = m_coordMatrix.Clone();
        mx.TransformPoints(points);
        */
        return points[0];   
    /* I have struct like that:
    struct CoordPoint{
        float x,y;
        public static implicit operator CoordPoint(System.Drawing.PointF p)
        {
            return new CoordPoint(p.X, p.Y);
        }
    }
    */
    }
```

When the m_zoom arrived at 10 or more,it will be abnormal.
The mouseWheel scroll quickly,it will also be abnormal.
For example,when I slowly scroll mousewheel at point (50,50) before m_zoom < 10,it will print m_scalePos:(50,50).
The exception will not print m_scale:(50,50),even throw OverflowException.

There are my test paint Code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (m_bmpBuffer == null)
        {
            ReSize(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        }
        m_graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle);

        PointF[] pts = new PointF[]{
            new PointF(20,20),
            new PointF(80,80),
            new PointF(20,80),
            new PointF(80,20),
            new PointF(0,0)
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length; i++)
        {
            pts[i] = (PointF)ScreenToCoord(pts[i]);
        }
        m_graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, pts[0], pts[1]);
        m_graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, pts[2], pts[3]);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_bmpBuffer, 0, 0);
 }
```

I  aim at implementing as this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbwhZ.png)

Comment: What is your problem? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The problem with attempt is, that you assume the mouse position is the new zoom center every time you scroll in/out. You need to rewrite your `OnMouseWheel` method so that when the zoom level changes, the mouse position isn't the *center* of your zoom but rather that the mouse position stays at the same relative position after changing the zoom. I'm guessing with your current implementation your view "wanders off" when you are not zooming at the center?

Comment: ReCoord() is wrong, it applies the transforms repeatedly.  it should start from an identity matrix instead.  Do keep in mind that Matrix is disposable, at least stop using Clone().

Comment: I am sorry for my little reputation so that I can't reply anyone.In my Recoord() it has matrix.reset()..What’s about @Manfred Radlwimmer means? Can you show me some code? Thank :).